# how would i see all environmental variables beginning with a specific term?

Tags: command-line, terminal, environment-variables

I'm just wondering how to list Environmental Variables that would begin with something specific (say i wanted all the Environmental Variables that began with "we") in OSX. i understand how to print them all but can't work out how to search for a specific one.

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1):

You can just pipe the `printenv` command through grep.

```
printenv | grep -i "we"
```

The `-i` flag tells grep to search case-insensitively.

Comment: That should probably be `grep -i '^we'`... Otherwise you're finding variables that *contain* "we" instead of *start with* "we", and also may have "we" in the value instead of the name...

Comment: hi, i actually worked this out shortly after posting. thanks for the help, everyone.